# Implement my enemy class to the Game Scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, sprite-kit

I'm still fairly new to programming and what I tried to do is the following: So I separated my Enemies from my game scene to a different class.
In the Enemy class.m file I declared 6 methods. Every method represents a new level, which will get called from the game scene.
So in the methods I declare the sprite's image, path, shooting particle type, etc..
Here's an example of the level 1 method in the `EnemyClass.m` file:

```
+(void)enemiesLevel1
{
EnemyName = @"enemy1";
SKSpriteNode* enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:EnemyName];
pathSpeed = 3;
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,400,400), NULL);
SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:path
                                    asOffset:NO
                                orientToPath:YES
                                    duration:pathSpeed];

SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];
SKAction *addEnemy = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [GameScene addChild: enemy];
}];
SKAction *enemySequence = [SKAction sequence:@[addEnemy, forever]];

[GameScene runAction: enemySequence];
}
```

However, Xcode is states two issues:

```
No known class method for selector "addChild"
```

and

```
No known class method for selector "runAction"
```

I'm calling the method from `GameScene.m` with:

```
[EnemyClass enemiesLevel1]
```

It may seem like a dumb question, but I am still new and I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you should create instance of EnemyClasss in your GameScene and then use it; your code should look like this;

In EnemyClass.m:

```
-(void)enemiesLevel1
{
EnemyName = @"enemy1";
SKSpriteNode* enemy = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:EnemyName];
pathSpeed = 3;
CGPathRef path = CGPathCreateWithEllipseInRect(CGRectMake(0,0,400,400), NULL);
SKAction *followTrack = [SKAction followPath:path
                                    asOffset:NO
                                orientToPath:YES
                                    duration:pathSpeed];

SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];
SKAction *addEnemy = [SKAction runBlock:^{
    [self addChild: enemy];
}];

SKAction *enemySequence = [SKAction sequence:@[addEnemy, forever]];

[self runAction: enemySequence];
}
```

In GameScene.m:

```
EnemyClass *enemy= [[EnemyClass alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
```

and then you can use:

```
[self addChild: [enemy enemiesLevel1]];
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, I edited my post immediately, thanks

Comment: Ah yes. I didn't see that.

Comment: enemiesLevel1 has a void return type. [self addChild:[enemy enemiesLevel1]] won't compile since addChild (presuming EnemyClass is a subclass of SKNode) expects a parameter of type "SKNode *".